# Lua 5.3 thinks socket.lua doesn't exist in a directory where it actually does exist

Tags: lua, luarocks

Here's a screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4Dqo44FM648VTVKVzBKSERldGc

I would like to have fun contributing to the development of an open source game but this problem is preventing me from doing this.

My LuaRocks install is configured for Lua 5.3 and is set to use MinGW's build tools. My OS is Windows 10 64 bit.

My Lua 5.3.2 binaries were provided by [this](http://joedf.users.sourceforge.net/luabuilds/) website (lua-5.3.2_Win64_bin.zip).

If you have an idea for a possible cause please post it.

Comment: Lua does not expand environment variable references in `package.path`, so `%APPDATA%` won't work. You need the real path. The LuaRocks installation script should have said that: "Note that the %APPDATA% element in the paths above is user specific and it MUST be replaced by its actual value."

Comment: Thanks for helping me siffiejoe, my Lua interpreter can now find socket.lua.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Lua does not expand environment variable references in package.path, so %APPDATA% won't work. You need the real path. The LuaRocks installation script should have said that: "Note that the %APPDATA% element in the paths above is user specific and it MUST be replaced by its actual value." - siffiejoe

Answer (score 3):

You have to resolve environment variables manually:

> [os.getenv](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.getenv) (varname)
>
> Returns the value of the process environment variable varname, or nil
>   if the variable is not defined.

So, in your case you need to obtain the %APPDATA% path first:

```
os.getenv("APPDATA")
```

*Returns: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming*

When searching for packages to load, Lua uses a pre-defined list of folders to search in. This list is defined in *[package.path](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.path)* which is a semicolon-delimited (;) string. To add a new folder, you must append it's path to *package.path*:

```
package.path = package.path .. ";" .. NEWFOLDER .. "\\?.lua"
```

Finally, your complete solution is this:

```
package.path = package.path .. ";" .. os.getenv("APPDATA") .. "\\luarocks\\share\\lua\\5.3\\?.lua"
local s = require("socket")
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me BotOfWar but the directory socket.lua is in, is already in my Lua module search path because I have a LUA_PATH environment variable, as I was instructed to make by LuaRocks when I installed it. I also have a LUA_CPATH environment variable defined. 

In the screenshot I've provided a link to, the console output shows that Lua tries to find socket.lua in the directory where its located but for some reason it fails. 

So I'm worried there may be malicious software on my PC because I can't think of another explanation for why this is happening.

Comment: @Joe912 Unlike Windows' cmd, Lua does not translate %APPDATA% into the real full path like C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming
Therefore:
_%APPDATA%\LuaRocks\share\lua\5.3\socket.lua_ doesn't exist!
_C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\LuaRocks\share\lua\5.3\socket.lua_ does exist.
You have to **"translate" %APPDATA% yourself** into a valid path.